# warning #10145 no action performed for file 'A.obj'

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran

I am under windows (as the obj extension shows).

I have two valid .f90 files `A.f90` and `B.f90` (placed in the same folder) provided to me, where `B.f90` uses `A.f90`, the code of `B.f90` being :

```
module B
use A
! ... stuff
```

The code of `A.f90` is

```
module A
! ... stuff
```

I compile `A.f90` with :

```
ifort -c -fpp A.f90
```

Now I would like to compile `B.f90` "while taking accound of" `A.f90`, that is, of its `.obj` file.

So I tried :

```
ifort -c B.f90 A.obj
```

which throws

ifort: warning #10145: no action performed for file 'A.obj'
at me.

Is the command

```
ifort -c B.f90
```

proper to compile `B.f90` "while taking accound of" `A.f90`, that is, of its `.obj` file ?

I would like `B.f90` it to be compiled "as `A.f90` is", as in fact I have a third `C.f90` (containing a `use B`) and that at the end I must run the command :

```
ifort -dll toto.dll A.o B.o C.o
```

to compile a dll while linking to all object files from A, B, C.

Comment: Are you trying to compile (link) `B.f90` to make an executable, or just create a new object `B.obj`?

Comment: I guess (see the edit to my question) that I only need to create `B.obj`, but as the code of it, in `B.f90` used the module `A`, I don't know in fact how to take the dependence in account : does the `use A` in `B.f90` suffice for this, or should something be specified (as I guess) in command to compile `B.f90` ?

Comment: I suggest reading [this question and its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12306740/3157076) for information.  Essentially, what you are doing is "working".  You can remove the `A.obj` from the compile line, because the information about the module contents comes from the module file created, which would be found automatically

Comment: @francescalus Thank, now it makes senses. You can write an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 2):

The information about module `A` that the compiler needs in order to compile file `B.f90` is not in file `A.f90` but in file `A.mod` (name of the module followed by `.mod` extension). The default is that `.mod` files are created in and read from the directory where `ifort` is run from.  Therefore, if you compile files in the right order (as you are doing), and run `ifort` from the same directory when you compile all these files, it will have access to the previously compiled module files, and everything will work fine with simple commands such as

```
ifort -c B.f90
```

If, at compilation time, a compiler does not have access to the module file of a module that is `use`d in the file currently compiled, an error will be isued and compilation will abort.